# бот игнорирует аргументы

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

команда нужна что бы отнимать баланс сервера у пользователей в определённом кол-ве (если они каким то образом/багом получили его), но бот игнорирует все значения кроме amount == 'all'. кто может помочь? буду очень благодарен.

код:

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def take(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount=None):
    if amount == "all":
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (0, member.id, ctx.guild.id,))
    elif int(amount) < 1:
        await ctx.send("Сумма не должна быть меньше 1")
    elif not amount.is_digit():
        await ctx.send("Должна быть сумма или all")
    else:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - ? WHERE id = ? AND guild_id = ?", (amount, member.id, ctx.guild.id,))
    
    db.commit()
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author} отобрал у пользователя {member} {amount} рублей')
```

Comment: а как передается значение all? цифрой или 'all' ?

Comment: значение all передается как 'all'

Comment: в первом if я так понял не 'None', а 'all'? думаю проблема в том, что когда вы отправляете какое-то значение, в SQL запрос вы передаете текстовое значение, попробуйте передать int(amount)

Comment: к сожалению это тоже не помогло

Comment: Ошибка возможно в том, что `is_digit()` написано через подчёркивание. У строки (если `amount` - это строка) есть метод `isdigit()`. Возникает исключение при вызове несуществующего метода и функция *"кирдык"*. Ну и не связано конкретно с вопросом, но проверку `elif not amount.is_digit()` надо бы поменять местами с `elif int(amount) < 1`. Да и проверки `amount` на `None` чего-то не видно (или зачем вообще давать этому параметру значение по-умолчанию?).

Comment: GrAnd, Anatoly Kritskiy , спасибо за помощь, всё заработало)